# UITableView segue to UITableView

Tags: uitableview, storyboard

I am very new to this area of iPhone app development and have been looking through some links to understand it.

The requirement of my app is very similar to a phone contacts app.

I need to have a TableView on my home page with a few names on it. Whenever a name is clicked, it should open up another TableView with has further details (like mobile phone number, home phone number etc.).

I have been able to create the first TableView with the name of people but am unable to create the 2nd one and link it with the first one. I am using Storyboards to achieve this.

Also, if there is some free source code available for such an app, then that will be great!

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueName" sender:self];
```

Comment: So, how do I carry data from the first TableView and display it in each cell of the second TableView?